# Order a list of calendar events in Javascript and add month name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of events in HTML:

```
<ol id="my-list">
  <li data-start="01-Jan-2019">Event on 01-Jan-2019</li>
  <li data-start="25-Dec-2018">Event on 25-Dec-2018</li>
  <li data-start="14-Feb-2018">Event on 14-Feb-2018</li>
  <li data-start="14-Jul-2019">Event on 14-Jul-2019</li>
  <li data-start="31-Oct-2019">Event on 31-Oct-2019</li>
  <li data-start="13-Oct-2019">Event on 13-Oct-2019</li>
  <li data-start="26-Oct-2016">Event on 26-Oct-2016</li>
  <li data-start="02-Dec-2018">Event on 02-Dec-2018</li>
  <li data-start="21-Dec-2018">Event on 21-Dec-2018</li>
  <li data-start="18-Dec-2018">Event on 18-Dec-2018</li>
</ol>
```

How can I modify the list to be:

```
<ol id="my-list">

    <span>October</span>

    <li data-start="01-Jan-2019">Event on 26-Oct-2016</li>

    <span>February</span>

    <li data-start="25-Dec-2018">Event on 14-Feb-2018</li>

    <span>December</span>

    <li data-start="14-Feb-2018">Event on 02-Dec-2018</li>
    <li data-start="14-Jul-2019">Event on 18-Dec-2018</li>
    <li data-start="31-Oct-2019">Event on 21-Dec-2018</li>
    <li data-start="13-Oct-2019">Event on 25-Dec-2018</li>

    <span>January</span>

    <li data-start="26-Oct-2016">Event on 01-Jan-2019</li>

    <span>July</span>

    <li data-start="02-Dec-2018">Event on 14-Jul-2019</li>

    <span>October</span>

    <li data-start="21-Dec-2018">Event on 13-Oct-2019</li>
    <li data-start="18-Dec-2018">Event on 31-Oct-2019</li>
</ol>
```

I can also use jQuery.

More specifically, I need to compare each date and see if the month has changed, then if it is, append the right month name.

First I ordered the events (source http://jsfiddle.net/greguarr/2fr0vmhu/):

```
var container = $("#my-list");
var items = $("#my-list li");

items.each(function() {
   // Convert the string in 'data-start' attribute to a more
   // standardized date format
   var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-start").split("-");
   var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
   standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
   $(this).attr("data-start", standardDate);
   console.log($(this).attr("data-start", standardDate));

});

items.sort(function(a,b){
    a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-start"));
    b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-start"));
    return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0;
}).each(function(){
    container.append(this);
});
```

Then I want to compare each event month name with its previous event month name and insert the name of the month only if the month changed.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @CertainPerformance in this specific case, it's the logic that I am looking for, not the code. More specifically, I don't know where to start

Comment: Often, when you have a programming objective, the first place to start is by trying to write some code - break the problem down into chunks, solve each chunk, put it together. SO isn't a code-writing service for when you haven't made any attempt yourself

Comment: okay, let me put in my approach then

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have actually solved the question at first attempt. Should I remove the question ?? Thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have answered my own question. It that cool ??

Comment: @CertainPerformance let me know please

Comment: Yes, answering your own question is allowed, but one should generally post a question + self-answer about something that has *some value* to future visitors, rather than a localized personal debugging issue. (also, `<div>`s should not be children of `<ol>`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the month of each event with the previous one and if it's different, append its name before the list item:

```
items.each(function(i) {
    var a1 = new Date($(this).data('start'));
    var b1 = new Date($(this).prev().data('start'));
    if (a1.getMonth() != b1.getMonth()) {
        $(this).before("<span>" + defineMonth(a1.getMonth()) + "</span>");
    }
});
```

Where defineMonth is a function to retrieve the name of the month:

```
function defineMonth(evt) {
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var n = month[evt];
  return n;
}
```